# Trying to understand (function(func) { func(); } in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Coming from C, every function needs a name that is used to call that specific function. but in the JavaScript code below. There is no name at all. So how does `function(func) { func(); }` calls the `something.push(function()` ?

Not to mention that `something.push(function()` doesn't even have an argument, which from C perspective, this is wrong

```
var something = [], 
  object = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: true
}

 for (let key in object){
   something.push(function() {
   console.log(key);
   });
 }

 something.forEach(function(func) { func(); }):
```

Comment: The first loop is pushing in a function that when called is going to print one of `object`'s keys  to the console. The second just executes every function in the array.

Comment: Note that the ability to pass functions as arguments (or otherwise treat functions as objects and create multiple references to them) is not a new ES6 feature, that's an old-school JS feature.

Comment: a function doesn't have to have an argument (same in c). in javascript (and also in some other languages) a function doesn't have to have a name either, such functions are called anonymous functions.  something.push() just added anonymous functions in its content.

Answer (score 2):

> Coming from C, every function needs a name that is used to call that specific function. but in the JavaScript code below, there is no name at all.

Well in JavaScript, that's just not the case – functions can indeed be **anonymous** (nameless) functions. Sometimes you'll hear them called "lambdas" or redundantly called "lambda functions".

But more importantly, functions are **first class** data members in JavaScript, meaning:

1. They can be **assigned to variables**

   ```
   let y = x => x + 5
   y(3)
   // 8
   ```
2. They can be **passed as arguments** to other functions

   ```
   let xs = [1,2,3]
   let y = x => 2 * x
   xs.map(y)
   // [2,4,6]
   ```
3. They can be **returned from a function**

   ```
   let add = x => {
     return y => x + y
   }
   let f = add(1)
   f(2)
   // 3
   ```
4. They can be **included in data structures**

   ```
   let pikachu = {
     number: 25,
     shock: enemy => enemy.damage(30),
     growl: enemy => enemy.sadden(40)
   }
   pikachu.growl(meowth)
   // "It's very effective!"
   ```

So what's the take away here? Well, in JavaScript, you need to think of functions as being no different than any other value (eg) `1`, `"foo"`, or `[{user: 'bob'}, {user: 'alice'}]` – conceptually, they are just *data* and they're all first class

---

**How to understand your code**

Here's your code affectionally reformatted by me. Since you originally asked about ES6, I'm going to substitute your lambdas with ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
let something = []
let object = { a: true, b: true, c: true }

for (let key in object) {
  something.push(() => console.log(key))
}

something.forEach(func => func())
// a
// b
// c
```

Using high level descriptors, the nature of this code is

1. iterate thru each key of `object`, add *some value* to `something`
2. iterate thru each value of `something`, do something with that value

In your case, *some value* is a function, but I want to show you what your code would look like if we used another kind of value

```js
let something = []
let object = { a: true, b: true, c: true }

for (let key in object) {
  // this time push a string, instead of an anonymous function
  something.push("the key is: " + key)
}

something.forEach(str => console.log(str))
// the key is: a
// the key is: b
// the key is: c
```

So now we can see how the code works when a different value type (String) is used. Aside from using a string, the only other thing we did was change

```
// from
func => func()

// to
str => console.log(str)
```

The reasoning here is

- in your original code, `something` is an **array of functions**, so for each of those functions, `func`, we call `func()`
- in the modified code, `something` is an **array of strings**, so for each of those strings, `str`, we call `console.log(str)`

---

**Dissection of Array.prototype.forEach**

The last remaining bit to understand is the super-powered [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function. Remember point number **2** in the first class capabilities: first class data members can be passed as arguments to other functions.

`forEach` expects its argument to be a function. So `forEach` is a function that accepts another function. This kind of function is called a [*higher-order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Don't let these fancy names distract you from their underlying simplicity. Making our own higher-order functions like `forEach` is actually really easy. Always just remember that functions are like any other value – below, we'll write our own version of `forEach` so you can see how it works

```js
let something = []
let object = { a: true, b: true, c: true }

// forEach accepts an array and some function, f
let forEach = (arr, f) => {
  // iterate thru each value of arr
  for (let value of arr) {
    // call f on each value
    f(value)
  }
}

for (let key in object) {
  something.push("the key is: " + key)
}

forEach(something, str => console.log(str))
// the key is: a
// the key is: b
// the key is: c
```

So now we see the string array working with our own `forEach` function. Let's make sure it works with your original lambda array, too.

```js
let something = []
let object = { a: true, b: true, c: true }

let forEach = (arr, f) => {
  for (let value of arr) {
    f(value)
  }
}

for (let key in object) {
  something.push(() => console.log(key))
}

forEach(something, func => { func() })
// a
// b
// c
```

---

**Remarks**

And that's it! Functions aren't special snowflakes in JavaScript. They're just like all the datums.

Coming from a C perspective, it might take awhile to think about functions in this way. But really, you should leave everything you understand about any language at the door when you're walking into the home of any new programming language. Each language has its own way of expressing itself yielding a unique set of strengths and weaknesses. By bringing in a "strength" of some language A to another language B, you might be substituting one of B's own strengths for one of it's weaknesses.

JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language making it rather suitable for imperative, object-oriented, and functional programming styles. Because of its jack-of-all-trades nature, it's probably not *the best* oop or fp language, but it's still rather impressive that it can express a particular solution to a problem in a wide variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is more abstract language than C. In JavaScript interpretter internally saves types and pointers of every variable. When you declare a function, it is internally saved somewhere in memory and **pointer** of that function is passed to whatever you passed it (here to `something.forEach`).

But, this is not pointer like in C, you cannot access its value (function address) nor you can change it. In JavaScript these pseudo-pointers are called "references". Simply, when you try to call something, interpretter engine will check its type. If its type type is a function, thread will do some preparations and then execute jump to memory location which function pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @nnnnnn. Of course, but according to OP's understanding of JavaScript (he is obviously beginner) and his attempting to find similarities with C, I tried to explain it in terms of pointers.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was just providing the relevant JS terminology for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The `something` array is storing references to functions, but not invoking them. In the `forEach` loop, each function within the array is being invoked.

To be fair, the naming is confusing. You could just as easily write:

```
something.forEach(function(storedFunction) { storedFunction(); }):
```

since it's a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

So, what's happening here is in the loop, we are [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) a `function` to `something` on each iteration. Assuming `something` is an array in this case.

Then, we call the collection's [foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function. The first argument in this function is always the current item over which we are iterating. In this case, we're iterating over the list of functions we built in the loop. Since these are functions, we can call them, which is what's happening for each one.

Here's an example to help illustrate:

```
// declare some functions
function a(){console.log('hi');}
function b(){console.log('there');}
function c(){console.log('friend');}
const ar = [];

// push the functions to the array
ar.push(a);
ar.push(b);
ar.push(c);
ar.push(a);

ar.forEach(function(func) {func();});

// console output:
// hi
// there
// friend
// hi
```

EDIT: I highly recommend you read [Mozilla's documentation of the function type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). If you go there and thoroughly read through it I think you'll have a very solid grasp of this concept.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are treated as objects. And in C you must be aware that not every object (value) needs to have a name, or doesn't need to be stored in a variable. Just like you can have​ `sum (4, 5);`. 4 and 5 are values not stored in variables.

To answer your question about how they will be called if they have no name, the function is passed as an argument to the push function. There the formal parameter must have some name. So it can be called by that name. In this case push doesn't call it but stores it in an array to be called later. It can be called by indexing into the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the usage of an *anonymous function* and a *closure*. It's pretty Javascript in a nutshell.

There I describe the code block per block :

**We create an array (like in C) :**

```
var something = [],
```

**We create an object (which is a collection of key=value)**

```
object = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: true
}
```

**We iterate through the elements of the object** *object*

```
for (let key in object) {
```

**There the show is on :**

```
something.push(function() {
```

Each object has a push function that allow to put elements dynamically inside of it.
What you see here is a *anonymous function* being used as an *argument*; it means that for each executions of *this* push function, a function that do :

```
console.log(key);
```

will be put inside the *something* array;

There after, the only thing that is done is a `callback` with *func()* :

```
something.forEach(function(func) { func(); }):
```

This means *forEach* elements of *something*, you will treat it as a **function** resulting in calling the precedent function stored with *push()*